# Почему получается ошибка Call to a member function getRow() on null in?

Tags: php, mysqli

При использовании данной библиотеки:
    https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php

Вызывая функцию:

```
$id = 1;
$db->getRow("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?i", $id);
```

Выходит ошибка: Call to a member function getRow() on null in почему, как решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где-то выше в коде, не произошло подключение к БД, по какой-либо причине.
В результате в `$db` нет ссылки на подключение. А вы не проверив это, пытаетесь с ним работать.

Как решить: проверить что именно лежит в `$db` и сделать так, чтобы там лежал именно handler БД